# MySQL Workbench rollback while open

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was working with **MySQL** Workbench to continue a schema I had started yesterday. After some work, I created a new EER Diagram and put some of the tables in it. Suddenly, I believe after pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, the whole thing rolled back to where I started and every table I had designed was now called "table1" in the schema.

Is there any way to recover the work lost?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench you can, like in many applications, undo changes and of course redo them -> see the Edit menu. Shortcut for redo is Shift+Ctrl+Z on Linux + Win, Shift+Command+Z on macOS.